# CNAME record pointing wrong host

Tags: cname

I'm using pythonanywhere.com to host a website, and I bought a domain "aquienvoto.uy", in my dns provider I created the following CNAME record:

[image: cname record]

And I get the following error at pythonanywhere.com...

[image: pythonanywhere error]

If I run dig command this is what I get...

```
www.aquienvoto.uy.  3600    IN  CNAME   webapp-543799.pythonanywhere.com.aquienvoto.uy.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: go edit your cname record again and make sure that you actually have webapp-543799.pythonanywhere.com instead of webapp-543799.pythonanywhere.com.aquienvoto.uy

Comment: My current configuration is the same as I posted before. What should I type in "Alias" field?

Comment: are there other dns options to set a cname record instead of an alias?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was missing a '.' at the end, correct configuration is webapp-543799.pythonanywhere.com.

Comment: aha! good catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer from nic.com.uy, the domain provider. I was missing a '.' at the end, correct configuration is webapp-543799.pythonanywhere.com.